# Accepting DateTime (Jodatime) as request method argument in SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jodatime

I have a model class

```java
class SomeClass {
  private DateTime myDate;
  // setter & getter
}
```

and a controller:

```java
@Controller
class MyController {
  @RequestMapping("...")
  public String doStuff(@ModelAttribute("myAttribute") SomeClass value) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

When calling this controller from a HTML5 form with an appropriate `<input type="datetime" .../>` field I get the following error:

> Field error in object 'myAttribute' on field 'myDate':
>   rejected value [2014-02-08T23:00:00.00Z]; codes
>   [typeMismatch.myAttribute.myDate,typeMismatch.myDate,typeMismatch.org.joda.time.DateTime,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [myAttribute.myDate,myDate]; arguments [];
>   default message [myDate]]; default message [Failed to convert
>   property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'org.joda.time.DateTime' for property 'myDate'; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of
>   type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.joda.time.DateTime] for
>   property 'myDate': **no matching editors or conversion strategy
>   found]**

This confuses me because as I understand `7.6.5 Configuring Formatting in Spring MVC` in the [manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html):

> Full support for the Joda Time formatting library is also installed if
>   Joda Time is present on the classpath.

The conversion should just work out of the box (I am using spring 4.0 and Joda time 2.3). At least it should find a converter even if the format may be wrong. However I thought that should try to configure the date format as explained in section `7.7 Configuring a global date & time format`. With some additional help from google about the format of HTML5 date fields and Javadoc I came up with this:

```xml
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="formatterRegistrars">
        <set>
          <bean class="org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaTimeFormatterRegistrar">
              <property name="useIsoFormat" value="true" />
          </bean>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

However the effect of those lines which I just inserted into my applicationContext.xml had no effect at all.

So what do I need to do to set things up correctly (additionally I want to avoid the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation on my model object, because my model doesn't know anything about HTML so it feels wrong to me to attach the information about the format in HTML5 on that object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the following in your spring servlet config file, to get the default conversions set up

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: Well... You are right. I skimmed over this option when I read through the manual because I thought that what I am trying to do has nothing to do with annotations. Whatever the guys at spring source thought when they planned this feature.